# Foreground detection without an image sequence

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, background-subtraction, object-recognition

I need to **detect the foreground object** on **an image** and cut it off from that image. There are lots of **background/foreground subtraction** or **object recognition** algorithms but these algorithms are working on the videos or image sequences. I have only **an image** (it can be a picture of a man in front of a white wall. ) as an input. Do you know any useful approaches that can be applicable on **a single image file** instead of video or image sequences.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a figure-ground segmentation algorithm. Does it have to be fully automatic? If you can draw an initial contour of the object by hand, you can use a class of algorithms called "active contours". If you need this to be fully automatic, you can use an algorithm called N-cuts.

If you are using MATLAB, and you are ok with semi-automatic segmentation, try the [Image Segmenter App](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/image-segmentation-using-the-image-segmenter-app.html) in the Image Processing Toolbox.

Answer (score 1):

search as an "saliency detection"
like
"Global contrast based salient region detection"
http://mmcheng.net/salobj/